# Cakephp pagination with Having Clause

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0

Is it possible to use below query with Cakephp pagination??

```
select u.email,(select count(*) from relatives as iu where iu.user_id=u.id ) as iu_count,(select count(*) from friends as ff where ff.user_id=u.id ) as ff_count from users as u having (iu_count>0 OR ff_count>0)
```

i tried to do this using cakephp pagination but it gives an error as "iu_count" and "ff_count"  are not available in selection part of query but they are available in Having clause. My cakephp pagination query is as below.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `abc`.`users` AS `User` WHERE 1 GROUP BY `User`.`id` having (iu_count>0 OR ff_count>0)
```

Need a help/guidance to work with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

today i googled more and find a solution which works for me. The solution is to override paginateCount method in Model.

Below is a overrided function.

```
public function paginateCount($conditions = null, $recursive = 0, $extra = array()) {
        $parameters = compact('conditions', 'recursive');

        if (isset($extra['group'])) {
            $parameters['fields'] = array("iu_count","ff_count");
            //$parameters['fields'] = $extra['group'];
            if (is_string($parameters['fields'])) {
                // pagination with single GROUP BY field
                if (substr($parameters['fields'], 0, 9) != 'DISTINCT ') {
                    $parameters['fields'] = 'DISTINCT ' . $parameters['fields'];
                }
                unset($extra['group']);
                $count = $this->find('count', array_merge($parameters, $extra));
            } else {
                // resort to inefficient method for multiple GROUP BY fields
                $count = $this->find('count', array_merge($parameters, $extra));
                $count = $this->getAffectedRows();
            }
        } else {
            // regular pagination
            $count = $this->find('count', array_merge($parameters, $extra));
        }
        return $count;
    }
```

Here "array("iu_count","ff_count");" are my virtual fields which i am using in HAVING clause. assign $extra['group'] to $parameter['fields'] if there are no virtual fields that needed in HAVING clause.

Hope this solution will help some one.